# How to find $r(t)$ such that $r(t_i)=0$ for given $t_i$.

Tags: polynomials

We have $t_i=\dfrac{2v_0^2\sin\theta\cos(\theta+\phi)}{g \cos^2\phi}$.

Is there a way to find the function $r(t)$ such that $r(t_i)=0$?

Were $\phi, \theta$ are constant and $r(t) \neq 0$ for $t \neq t_i$

In other words, finding a polynomial given its root.

Comment: What is the relationship between $t$ and $t_i$?

Comment: Is something wrong with $r(t)=0 $for all $t$?  More seriously, do you want subscripts of $i$ on $\theta$ and $\phi$ and to have $r(t) \neq 0$ for $t \neq$ any $t_i$?

Comment: $t_i$ is the root of $r(t)$

Comment: Is this an equation from projectile motion, where $t_i$ is the time of impact and $r(t)$ is the altitude at time $t$?  Normally you have $r(t)$ first and solve $r(t)=0$ to get $t_i$, not the other way around.  There are many functions that satisfy $r(t_i)=0$

Comment: $\phi$ and $\theta$ are constant, that's why I did not include the subscripts. Yes $r(t) \neq 0$ for any $t \neq t_i$

Comment: $r(t)= t - \frac{2v_0^2\sin\theta\cos(\theta+\phi)}{g \cos^2\phi}$ is the simplest polynomial with the given restrictions (as I assume that $v_0$ and $g$ are also constants).

Comment: $$r\left( t \right) ={ \left( { t }_{ i }-t \right)  }^{ 2 }$$
is an example of that functions. If $\theta,  \phi$ are arbitrarily constants, I will choose them such that $t_i=\dfrac{2v_0^2\sin\theta\cos(\theta+\phi)}{g \cos^2\phi}=\dfrac{v_0^2}{g}$. In your problem something is missing.